# fs::directory_iterator return empty list when greek letter occur in path

Tags: c++, filesystems

To scan files in folder I use code:

```
cout<<filepath; // for debug purposes
fs::path path(filepath);
fs::directory_iterator iterator = fs::directory_iterator(path);
for(const fs::directory_entry & entry : iterator)
{
    cout<<entry<<std::endl;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Code works perfect, until greek letter occur in filepath eg: `E:\projects\unifications\testΣ`, then `fs::directory_iterator` return empty list. I'm sure the folder `testΣ` exists and there are files in it.